# (Spring controller) The requirement sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I have the following jsp:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="fare">
    <div><fmt:message key="createfares.name" /></div>
    <div><form:input path="name" type="text"></form:input> </div>
    <div><fmt:message key="createfares.amount" /></div>
    <div><form:input path="amount" type="number" min="0" step="0.01"></form:input></div>
    <div><fmt:message key="createfares.startDate" /></div>
    <div><input name="startDate" type="date"/> </div>
    <div><fmt:message key="createfares.endDate" /></div>
    <div><input name="endDate" type="date"/> </div>
    <div><fmt:message key="createfares.description" /></div>
    <form:textarea path="description" cols="125" /> 
     <div><form:errors path="*"/></div>
    <fmt:message key="modifyfare.note" />
    <div class="submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="<fmt:message key="tooltip.modifyfare" />"></div>
</form:form>
```

And I have the following controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/modify/{idFare}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getModifyFare(@PathVariable String idFare, ModelMap model)

@RequestMapping(value="/modify/{idFare}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postModifyFare(@PathVariable String idFare, @ModelAttribute("fare") @Valid Fare fare, ModelMap model,
        BindingResult result, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String startDate, @RequestParam(required = false) String endDate)
```

The GET works perfectly, but the POST always says that "the requirement sent by the client was syntactically incorrect".

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I have deleted "ModelMap model" that I don't use in this post and it works.

Answer (score 1):

In the signature of the Controller's method to handle POST, you have both RedirectAttributes and ModelMap. These two types are for storing variables in the Model. They are maybe in conflict. Try to remove one of them.